# When I delete a GCP project, is the service account created in that project deleted?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I delete a GCP project, is the service account created in that project deleted?

Example)
First, create a service account A1 (A1@A.iam.gserviceaccount.com) in project A.
Then give A1 access to Project B.

Will A1 still exist if project A is deleted?
If so, what happens to A1 if project B is deleted?
Is it possible to reuse by granting access rights to other projects?

I want to know how service accounts that are not explicitly deleted are treated.

Answer (score 1):

If project A is deleted, service account A1 will be deleted.

If project A and service account A1 both exist, and project B is deleted, A1 is possible to reuse by granting access rights to other project.

I recommend these two topics which shows you details of “[Service account permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#service_account_permissions)” and “[Creating and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-list-gcloud)”

Comment: Thank you ! Certainly, it was confirmed that if project A was deleted, A1 could not be used in project B.